# Importing CSS into Material-UI Themes?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

How can I import existing CSS files as part of a Material-UI theme?

I have an existing product look-and-feel that I'm working to "closely match" with a Material-UI theme. As part of the them I want to import a few existing CSS files from the original product -- these files include a styles reset, some defaults, and variables.

When using Material-UI's `ThemeProvider`, to switch themes, I only want these items to be active when the appropriate theme is selected.

Where can I put these imports in Material-UI's theme creation process to have them import properly?

Comment: Do you want to keep ThemeProvider in your component as well or you just want to replace with css file?

Comment: I want to keep `ThemeProvider`. The existing CSS files set baseline defaults I want enabled when a particular theme is enabled, and I don't want to use them when another is set. So trying to import them as part of the theme itself.